# I'm unable to add new pages using Pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.LETTER);
        document.addPage(page);
        addText(document, page);
        document.save("C:/Java/cda.pdf");
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void addText(PDDocument document, PDPage page) {

    try {

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,
                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
        float sY = 750;
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(60, sY);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
            contentStream.showText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.");
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -18);
            System.out.println(sY - 18);
            sY = sY - 18;
            if (sY - 18 < 18) {
                contentStream.endText();
                contentStream.close();
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, new PDPage(PDRectangle.LETTER),
                        PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);
                contentStream.beginText();
                sY = 750;
            }
        }
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- for single-page code working fine but when content is exceeding the first page then it won't add a new 
  page
- unable to find what I'm missing
- I think the problem is in 'if' block of addText()

Comment: If the answer helped, please press the checkmark to make it the accepted answer. If the answer didn't help, then please make a comment explaining what happened / didn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
document.addPage(page);
```

a second time too. Your code in the question creates a second page content stream in an "orphan" PDPage object, and doesn't add it to the document.

I haven't rewritten the code because you'll need some refactoring, because addText() already has a PDPage object.